# unsupported Media type 415 for file upload with Spring mvc restcontroller and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, ng-file-upload, media-type

When i am trying to hit the angularjs $http.post  which contains file upload details its giving me unsupported media type. I am using backend spring mvc rest controller. The following is the code snippet.

```html
    <ul><li><h4>Document Type</h4>
    <select name="docType"  ng-model="docType" name="docType">
    <option value="Report1">Report1</option> 
    <option value="Report2">Report2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="file" ng-model-instant id="fileToUpload" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" />
    </li>
    <li><h4>Comments:</h4><textarea></textarea></li>
    <li><button  class="btn-panel-blue"  type="submit">Saves</button></li>
    <li><a href="#/searchProjects">Cancel</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```js
angular.module('app')
.controller('prjCntrl', function ($scope,projectService, sharedService, $location, $log, $http, $state) {
 $scope.setFiles = function(element) {
     $scope.$apply(function(scope) {
         $scope.uploadedFile ;
         for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
          $scope.uploadedFile=element.files[i];
          break;
         }
       });
     };
 $scope.updateProject = function updateProject()
 {
  var formData=new FormData();
  formData.append('docType',angular.toJson($scope.projectData.docType,true));
  formData.append("uploadFile",$scope.uploadedFile);
  var url=baseURL + '/updateProject.do';
  $http.post(url, formData, { transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} })
        .success(function(){alert("success");})
        .error(function(){ });
 };
}
);
```

and here is my java code.

```
    @RestController
    @MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,  
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,          
    maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)
    public class ProjectController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/updateProject.do",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers ="Accept=multipart/form-data", consumes={"multipart/form-data"}, produces={"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"})
        public @ResponseBody String updateProjectDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,  @RequestBody ProjectForm command)
        {
            contractProjectsService.saveProject(command);
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

here is the header information from chrome headers/request and response data

```
    **General:**
    Request URL:http://localhost:9090/SpringMVCAngularJS/updateProject.do
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
    Remote Address:[::1]:9090
    ***Response Headers:***
    view source
    Content-Language:en
    Content-Length:1048
    Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
    Date:Wed, 03 Aug 2016 15:06:05 GMT
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    ***Request Headers:***
    view source
    Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Authorization:Basic YmVlcDpib29w
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:1011
    Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=---- WebKitFormBoundaryagdf0LOX4AuXY6SI
    Cookie:JSESSIONID=96052E348C6E52F53A594A179E65DE6D
    Host:localhost:9090
    Origin:http://localhost:9090
    Referer:http://localhost:9090/SpringMVCAngularJS/index.html
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
```

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: This is not related to ng-file-upload.

Answer (score 0):

try to send the comment or other data in request header and send file to contoller ,in  controller use" @Requestpart" for accepting file. Use below code for reference..

```
@Produces("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseCodeModel fileUpload(@RequestPart MultipartFile file,
            @RequestHeader(value = "comment") String comment,
            )
```

Comment: Hi, Still the same result. Unsupported media type error is coming.